# How to do a simple linear fit?

Tags: linear, fitting, odds-ratio, epidemiology

I want to use a simple linear fit of OR (odd ratio) vs exposure value for subsequent groups in order to predict risk for each mid-point in the population exposure categories.
Ok it is not clear saying like but it is a method using in a publication that I am trying to understand for weeks (Legler et al. 2015, Obesity, Diabetes and Associatied costs of exposure to Endocrine-Disrupting chemicals in the European Union).

In the publication they have an example, they took "a published OR (= 1.45)
that was applied to the exposure distribution subsdivided into 0 to 9th, 10th to 24th, 25th to 49th, 50th to 74th, 75th to 89th, and 90th to 99th percentiles." What is that mean ? How from the OR it could be applied to the exposure subdivided ?
" Given that the effect measure was derived from a study population subdivided into percentile exposure groups, which did not match directly to the exposure groups available for the European population, the risks were linearly interpolated as follows. For published epidemiological results divided into
quantiles, each was assigned an exposure value as the midpoint
or median value in that group. The no effect level was taken to
be the midpoint for the highest group with a nonsignificant association
(P < .05). Taking that point as a baseline (OR = 1.0),
a simple linear fit of OR vs exposure value for subsequent groups
was used to predict risk for each midpoint in the population
exposure categories." This part is also unclear, how do they do the siple linear fit ?
After calculation of the appropriate OR for each exposed
group, the OR was multiplied against the annual incidence of
diabetes identified in the EPIC cohorts between 1991 and 2007
from 8 of the 10 EPIC countries to calculate an incident rate in
the presence of phthalate exposure (from an other study). After subtraction of the baseline rate of diabetes, the incremental rate of diabetes was
applied against the population estimate of 50 to 64 year olds.

I am a young student in toxicology and I am not a statistician and for me, it is not clear at all. Hope you can help me.